# Equivalent Class in Android

Tags: android, nsurlrequest

Is there and equivalent `NSURLRequest` (iOS) in android? So i can extend my class and gets the utility methods? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you are trying to accomplish, and then we can tell you how to do it in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html).

Comment: Much water has flown under the bridge since Mar'11. Now it is recommended to use `HttpURLConnection` on Gingerbread and better.

Answer (score 1):

Apache `HTTPClient` has fewer bugs on Eclair and Froyo. It is the best choice for these releases.

And [according to the android team](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) you should be using [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) on Gingerbread and better.
It has a pretty useful API that is just useful to develop a networking client application. It has improved response caching and improved compression technique on Android 2.3 and above. That reduces network use, improves speed and saves battery.

Answer (score 0):

I've not developed for iOS but looking at the summary of NSURLRequest I think you'll probably get by with the URL class: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html

Comment: It will not give me any utility methods. I want a way to see for instance if the connection as failed.

Comment: It will throw an IOException if connection fails, catch that and there you have it.